# First common element from different lists of numbers

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tree, numbers

I am trying to find the first common number (FCN) from e.g. 5 individual number lists. **For example the 5 number lists are these ones**:

```
list_1 = [13579875, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
list_2 = [1856721, 25724, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
list_3 = [2354074, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
list_4 = [533878, 651, 658, 8654,1357, 1254, 9, 68971]
list_5 = [567432, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
```

So ultimately, I want to be taking one pair of lists at a time and checking what is their FCN. In my mind, I would need to find the index of the first match. So between list_1 and list_2, the FCN is 3541 (index 2 for list_1 and index 2 for list_2 as well). Then I would have to compare list_1 with list_3 and find their FCN which is 25732. At any point, I would have to remember the FCN from the comparison of the list pairs. Ultimate purpose for building a tree that would show the association of the numbers. Then after comparing list_1 with all lists up to list_5, I would then start comparing list_2 with all other lists, until all possible comparisons were done.

I thought of solving it by having two for loops but I am not able to combine them into one function. This is all I have:

```
compare_lists = []
for i in list_1: 
       if i in list_2:
           compare_lists.append(1)
       else: 
           compare_lists.append(0)
print compare_lists
```

And for the part that I find the index of the FCN, I have this:

```
indexFCN_a = ""
indexFCN_b = ""
for a in list_1:
    if a in list_2: 
        indexFCN_a = list_1.index(a)
        indexFCN_b = list_2.index(a)
        print indexFCN_a
        break
```

**Obviously, one of my main problems, is that these need to be in one function and I am not quite sure on how to do this correctly.** I tried, but it's not quite what it should be. **Can you give an answer where this is in a function?** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am sure though that this task can be solved much more efficiently so if you have any ideas please share them. Please keep in mind that the ultimate purpose store the FCN for each comparison, for building a tree that would show the number associations.

Please see comments for further explanation. 
Also: how could I be keeping track to the number of times an element is the FCN? So the expected output for this question is: 3541 - 3 times, 25732 - 3 times, 68971 - 4 times.

Comment: What do you mean, least common number? You mean a number when combined over all lists is least common?

Comment: It's when comparing the two lists, it's the first number that it's common between the two lists. So for example with list_1 and list_2 the LCN is 3541.

Comment: @HR123r What about my answer?

Comment: @HR123r What is the actual expected answer?

Comment: So for the test case - what is your expected output? is it 3541?

Comment: @Kasra's answer assumes that `indexLCN_a` is always the same as `indexLCN_b`. It that the case?

Comment: @gabhijit The expected output is like Kasra's answer where I could have the answers of each comparison retrieved individually.  The index in the end might not be necessary. The importance is that a tree needs to be built out of this showing the relationship of the numbers. So if this can be done without needing to know the index then O.K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combination` to get the desire pairs and use `izip` to zip your lists and compare the elements in same index.

Also as a more elegant way you can put your lists within a dictionary like following :

```
d={
'list_1':[13579875, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_2' : [1856721, 25724, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_3' : [2354074, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_4' : [533878, 651, 658, 8654,1357, 1254, 9, 68971],
'list_5' : [567432, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]}

names=['list_1','list_2','list_3','list_4','list_5']
from itertools import combinations,izip
for i,j in combinations(names,2):
  for k,t in izip(d[i],d[j]):
    if k==t:
        print (i,j),'value:{}-index:{}'.format(k,d[i].index(k))
        break
```

result :

```
('list_1', 'list_2') value:3541-index:2
('list_1', 'list_3') value:25732-index:1
('list_1', 'list_4') value:68971-index:7
('list_1', 'list_5') value:25732-index:1
('list_2', 'list_3') value:3541-index:2
('list_2', 'list_4') value:68971-index:7
('list_2', 'list_5') value:3541-index:2
('list_3', 'list_4') value:68971-index:7
('list_3', 'list_5') value:25732-index:1
('list_4', 'list_5') value:68971-index:7
```

Note : the `zip` function will give you the columns of given iterables for example ,`itertools.izip` is like `zip` but it returns a generator of columns instead of a list:

```
>>> l1=['a','b','c']
>>> l2=[1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(l1,l2)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

So after the long discussion if you want to get the count of same elements you can use `collections.Counter` and use `Counter.most_common(N)` to get the most N common items :

```
d={
'list_1':[13579875, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_2' : [1856721, 25724, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_3' : [2354074, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_4' : [533878, 651, 658, 8654,1357, 1254, 9, 68971],
'list_5' : [567432, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]}

names=['list_1','list_2','list_3','list_4','list_5']
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter
CNT=Counter()
for i,j in combinations(names,2):
  for k,t in zip(d[i],d[j]):
    if k==t:
        CNT.update([k])
        break
print CNT
print CNT.most_common(1)
```

result:

```
Counter({68971: 4, 25732: 3, 3541: 3})
[(68971, 4)]
```

And if you dont want the equal elements in different index but fist match you can use following code :

```
d={
'list_1':[13579875, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546],
'list_2' : [1856721, 25724, 56732,3541, 1567, 20546,3541, 10, 68971],
'list_3' : [2354074, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971],
'list_4' : [533878, 651, 658, 8654,1357, 1254],
'list_5' : [567432, 25732, 3541, 56732, 20546, 10, 68971]}

names=['list_1','list_2','list_3','list_4','list_5']
from itertools import combinations,izip
for i,j in combinations(names,2):
  for ind,k in enumerate(d[i]):
    if k in d[j]:
        print (i,j),'value:{}-index for {}:{},index for {}:{}'.format(k,i,ind,j,d[j].index(k))
        break
```

result :

```
('list_1', 'list_2') value:3541-index for list_1:2,index for list_2:3
('list_1', 'list_3') value:25732-index for list_1:1,index for list_3:1
('list_1', 'list_5') value:25732-index for list_1:1,index for list_5:1
('list_2', 'list_3') value:56732-index for list_2:2,index for list_3:3
('list_2', 'list_5') value:56732-index for list_2:2,index for list_5:3
('list_3', 'list_5') value:25732-index for list_3:1,index for list_5:1
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is closer to what I want. To understand what you did: put lists in a dictionary, where list_x is the key and the actual list is the value. **Is there a way that this could be automated with a different command, instead of manually putting the lists into the dictionary?** Then created a different list called "names" where you list the names of the lists. Then went through

Comment: @HR123r Yeah it can be done automatically and the reason that i putted the names in a list is for the order, other wise you can use `d.keys`

Comment: @HR123r Do you have your lists within any data structure?

Comment: @HR123r, can you add your expected output because this does not find every common element in your sublists

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It shouldn't find every common just the first match!

Comment: @Kasra, where did you get that from  `least/last common number`? That is completely contradictory, the last common number is `68971` in list1 and list2 not 3541

Comment: @PadraicCunningham From long explanation below that

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think its a mistake by OP although you may be right as is though about this already but from the preceding explanation i interpret this answer. and in other wise i can change it very good. just need to hear the OP's explains.

Comment: if the OP provided the expected output like they have been asked for multiple times it would help

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Do you remember the `\w+` for append to file? :D and that answer with multiple edit that day?

Comment: @Kasra Your answer is the best so far. The lists are all going to be in one file. Can you explain what i, j, k, t represent please, to help me understand this better?  So the expected output would be as I gave a few examples in my question, that out of all individual comparisons we get the LCN. This LCN can then be retrieved individually to generate a tree. So the expected output: list_1 vs list_2 : 3541, list_1 vs list_3: 25732, list_1 vs list_4: 68971, list_1 vs list_5: 25732 and so on as Kasra answered it.

Comment: @HR123r, kasra's answer looks for elements at matching indexes which is not  remotely related to  *I am trying to find the least/last common number*, if you only want to find matching elements that also share the same index  then add that information to your question

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am sorry, I can't see that Kasra's answer finds elements at matching indexes. What I wanted, and what Kasra gave is to compare 2 lists at a time, and return the first matching element of the lists (and it's index). In this case because the lists are of same length the index is the same for both lists. But there could be a case where the lists could be of different length and so the index of the common element in list_1 would be different for the index of the same common element in list_X. So in that case, things get more complicated.

Comment: @HR123r OK, for understanding the answer you need to know how `zip` works. and for cases that the length of lists are not the same if you want just the match elements in same indax using zip is fine otherwise for example for `l=[1,2,3,4]` and `l2=[2,5,6]` the result must be 2 am i right?

Comment: @HR123r, then you don't understand what zip does. The answer only matches elements at exactly the same index in each list and will truncate any longer lists. If you added an example where elements are at different indexes and had different length lists with the full expected output your question would be a lot clearer.

Comment: @HR123r Also in What kind if file you have your lists?

Comment: @Kasra Excellent! So to analyze your answer, pls correct if wrong:       for i,j in combinations(names,2):  # i is e.g. list_1, j is e.g. list_2
  for k,t in zip(d[i],d[j]):  # k is the first element of list_1, t is the first element of list_2 of the columns made from the dictionary
    if k==t:    #if the element is the same between the two lists 
        CNT.update([k])   #you update the counter for k element. 
        break   #continue to the 2nd elements of the two lists. 
print CNT

Comment: @HR123r, this still only looks for elements that are at the same index,this cannot possibly work based on your requirements. change the last list to `[567432,3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]` where my code returns `first common between list_4 and list_5 index is 6 and element is 68971` this would return nothing

Comment: @Kasra the only thing that is left is that these lists come from a file. So is the idea to read the file line by line and updating "d" would be correct? Comment please? Thanks

Comment: @HR123r Yeah you understand the answer well, about your file as i asked what kind of file you have?

Comment: @Kasra, your answer is actually wrong, you only look at the elements at the same index, your edit makes no difference, zip groups elements at the same indexes and truncates the longer list when the lists are not the same length.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In the last line of the answer i mentioned that in that case OP needs to use a nested loop, SO in not a code writing service i have gave a lot of clue to OP!

Comment: @HR123r, the simple answer is you **cannot** use zip, you need to compare all elements against each other

Comment: @Kasra, your answer is wrong for the same size or different size lists, it might not be a code writing service but you should not pretend your answer is correct when it is completely wrong. You only check common indexes which is not the correct approach for any list

Comment: @HR123r I mentioned that in that case you couldn't use `zip` instead you can use a nested loop or you can use `in` operation to check the membership in the second list in each pair comparesion

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How you say **completely wrong**???? Since i said that this is for the case that OP wants the elements with same index????? and in other case you forced me to add that to answer!!!

Comment: @Kasra, *l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4] and l2 = [2,5,6] the LCN is 2. So with zip would this still return 2* no your code won't return 2 `[567432, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971,4]` break your code, same size list but no elements at the same index, my code `first common between list_4 and list_5 index is 6 and element is 68971`, your code == nothing so completely wrong

Comment: Your edit just adds even further complexity, a full linear scan with in and another with 2 more with index, horribly inefficient, you have four  loops on top of the building of the combinations

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I print the index for 2 elements for demonstrating the   result else there is no need to do that, also this problem have a lot of case...

Comment: @Kasra, sometimes it is easier to just admit your answer is bad and inefficient. Your first code is plain completely wrong, there is no doubt about it.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the lists first and use bisect:

```
list_1 = [13579875, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
list_2 = [1856721, 25724, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
list_3 = [2354074, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]
list_4 = [533878, 651, 658, 8654, 1357, 1254, 9, 68971]
list_5 = [567432, 25732, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971]

from bisect import bisect
lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5]
srt = list(map(sorted, lists))
from itertools import islice

def get_lcn():
    out = []
    for ind, l in enumerate(lists[:-1]):
        out.append([])
        for ind2, sub in enumerate(islice(srt, ind+1, None), 1):
            for ele in l:
                b = bisect(sub, ele, hi=len(l) - 1)
                if ele > sub[b-1]:
                    continue
                if ele == sub[b-1]:
                    out[-1].append(ele)
                    break
    return out

print(get_lcn())
```

Output:

```
[[3541, 25732, 68971, 25732], [3541, 68971, 3541], [68971, 25732], [68971]]
```

Still unclear what you actually want but you could build a dict first mapping elements to indexes:

```
lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5]


from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

for ind, l in enumerate(lists, 1):
    k = "list_{}".format(ind)
    for ind, ele in enumerate(l):
        d[k][ele] = ind

from itertools import islice
for ind, sub in enumerate(lists, 1):
    k = "list_{}".format(ind)
    for ind2, sub2 in enumerate(islice(lists, ind,None),1):
        for ind3, ele in enumerate(sub2):
            if ele in d[k]:
                print("first common between {} and {} at indexes {}, {} "
                      "and element is {}".format(k, "list_{}".format(ind2+ind), d[k][ele], ind3, ele))
                break
    print(" ")
```

Output:

```
first common between list_1 and list_2 at indexes 2, 2 and element is 3541
first common between list_1 and list_3 at indexes 1, 1 and element is 25732
first common between list_1 and list_4 at indexes 7, 7 and element is 68971
first common between list_1 and list_5 at indexes 2, 1 and element is 3541

first common between list_2 and list_3 at indexes 2, 2 and element is 3541
first common between list_2 and list_4 at indexes 7, 7 and element is 68971
first common between list_2 and list_5 at indexes 2, 1 and element is 3541

first common between list_3 and list_4 at indexes 7, 7 and element is 68971
first common between list_3 and list_5 at indexes 2, 1 and element is 3541

first common between list_4 and list_5 at indexes 7, 6 and element is 68971
```

If you want to find the first match anywhere then zip will **not** work, zip will zip elements together that are at the same index and truncate any longer list losing elements. So your accepted answer is completely wrong which can be tested with:

```
 [567432, 3541, 56732, 1567, 20546, 10, 68971,4]
```

which should return index 6 and 68971 as the common element between list 4 and 5 but returns nothing.

The last code has two loops over the lists, and a single loop over the elements of each sublist with two 0(1) lookups

Comment: Sorting the lists, wouldn't be good because I want to retain the relationship of the numbers within each list. So in this case, you answer is not helpful. I apologize for not giving replies to your comments sooner but my PC went to an unexpected boot and shut down.

Comment: @HR123r,  the second part does not sort the lists, it finds the first common element. It is still unclear what you actually want,  `least/last common number ` are two completely different things

Comment: I need the first common element. I will change my question to make it clear. Thanks.

Comment: @still i think this answer has less efficient than mine ( if don't consider 2 `list.index` in my answer because that's for demonstrating the validity of code)

Comment: @Kasra, no it is not, apart from that it is correct as opposed to your completely wrong first answer, the OP also mentioned indexes which mine provides with no added complexity There is no need to think or wonder your answer is about as inefficient as it gets

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think we need to terminate this discussion we said a lot of stuffs in answers if our purpose is that OP understand his/shes miss understanding or learn new things i think we have done that!

Comment: @Kasra, the best thing for the OP would be to explain that the answer they accepted is wrong. It is also misleading for anyone else who comes on the question facing a similar issue.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Why its wrong ??? since you have said in your answer that *Still unclear what you actually want* So OP knows that what answer is correct you can not judge from OPs side!!!!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Also I mentioned all the scenarios and I said that first recipe if for what case and other for what, I didn't gave an answer and lost for ever. I explained all the cases!!!!!!

Comment: @Kasra, I am not going to bang my head against the wall. Your answer is wrong, the OP  told you that the lists can be different sizes and the indexes are not always going to match up, you always argue black is white but in this case Stevie Wonder could see your answer is wrong so  that is really the end of the discussion.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham :) and i said the first part is for the example in question and its a case and there is no disadvantage in it. and in last parts i gave a correct and general answer SO my answer is not wrong bro! thanks for all taking time!

Comment: @Kasra. whatever you want to tell yourself, go ahead ;)

Comment: @Kasra, I think this singer would be more appropriate https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imsB543zqSM

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

I am assuming a few things - all lists have equal lengths. Then in that case something like -

```
filter(lambda (a,b): a == b, zip(list_1, list_2))[0][0]
```

Edit:
You can do above for all combinations of lists

```
from itertools import combinations
min = 1000000000000 # some very large number
for x,y in combinations((list_1, list_2, list_3, list_4, list_5), 2):
    min_2 = filter(lambda (a,b): a == b, zip(x, y))[0][0]
    print min_2
    if min_2 < min: 
        min = min_2 

print min
```

Following should give you what you want

Basically, comparing element by element. If they are equal, we collect them and then take the first element of the tuple at index 0.

Is this what you want?

Comment: Reason for down voting?